# Selenium IDE 'times' loop, doesn't return loop index?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I can't seem to get the index value (current loop id) using the 'times' method in Selenium IDE.  I'm using the latest and using it in FFox.  I found a reference that states that there's a baked in variable I can use, but I never get the value it just returns the string as if it doesn't exist (ref url: https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/times)
Anyone know the proper syntax for getting the loop index for 'times' method?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work when wrapping the 'times' method with execute script if anyone ever encounters this...
[image]